# Install Sitecore 9.1 Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DnsName' - parameter doesn't exist in the json config

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I run in this error by run `Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path createcert.json`.

The json file is from the xp0 package and it contains no parameter `DnsName`. I just found a variable like this:

```
"Variables": {
    "Root.Cert.DnsName": "[concat('DO_NOT_TRUST_', parameter('RootCertFileName'))]"
```

The error:

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate argument on parameter
>   'DnsName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is
>   not null or empty, and then try the command again. At
>   C:\ops\int\SIF\install.ps1:10 char:1
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration @createcert
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 2):

The DNSName variable used by the `CreateRootCert` task is taken from that `SIF` variable. As it has a default, you don't need to supply anything.

The error you got would have been from the `CreateSignedCert` task, which in turn links back to the "CertificateName" parameter.

You would need to run something like `Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\createcert.json -CertificateName mysite.somedomain.com` to have it create a self-signed cert.