# Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DnsName'

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

I'm installing a pre-release version `10.1.3`.
For this I have installed `10.1.2` using the Graphical setup.
Then placed these files in the root folder of the extracted `10.1.2` files.

```
- Sitecore 10.1.3 rev. 008034 (DELTA WDP XM1 packages).zip
- Sitecore 10.1.3 rev. 008034 (DELTA WDP XP0 packages).zip
- Sitecore 10.1.3 rev. 008034 (DELTA WDP XP1 packages).zip
```

In the `XP0-SingleDeveloper.json` file and set the `Update` parameter to `true`.

Now when I execute this command in Powershell `Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json` I see this error:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DnsName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration  -Path .\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:07
Invoke-NewSignedCertificateTask : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DnsName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command
again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.3.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:47
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-NewSignedCertificateTask], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Invoke-NewSignedCertificateTask
```

Also, if this was success, will it create a new instance with v10.1.3 or will it update the existing instance, because I have not changed any other setting in the XP0-SingleDeveloper.json.

Comment: Did you try this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15315/install-sitecore-9-1-cannot-validate-argument-on-parameter-dnsname-parameter

Comment: @SumitBhatia Yes I did. It's the same error even after that

Comment: Whenever I run into such problems, I do a full uninstall and manually check that everything has been uninstalled, so hosts file, IIS, certificates, databases, indexes, etc.  I also make sure to run the classic command: 

`Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA`

Comment: When doing a manual uninstall, also check for any services that need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The **xp0-SingleDeveloper.json** file has a section where it pulls in other config files (namely **Sitecore-XP0.json**):

```
"Includes": {
    "SitecoreXP0": {
        "Source": ".\\Sitecore-XP0.json"
    }
},
```

Within the Sitecore-XP0.json file, there is a parameter called DnsName, which defaults to using the SiteName parameter (which defaults to 'Sitecore'):

```
"DnsName" :{
    "Type": "string",
    "Reference": "SiteName",
    "Description": "The dns name of the site."
},
```

So it looks like this parameter may not have been set properly. Please review your Sitecore-XP0.json file and confirm SiteName parameter has been set. The value should be the root domain only (i.e. not include http:// prefix). The value used should be resolvable on your local instance.

Alternatively, you can pass in those parameters at the command line. For example:

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json
> -SiteName your-domain.com

I think you will also need to update the package parameter in relevant config files to point to the new delta packages. So in Sitecore-XP0.json:

```
"Package": {
    "Type": "string",
    "Description": "The path to the Web Deploy package to deploy.",
    "DefaultValue": ""
},
```